# What are the rights needed by an AzureAD app in order to run the command Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy from AzureAdPreview Module (Powershell)?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, rights, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I am the owner of an Azure AD registered application, and I need to run the command Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy from AzureAdPreview Module (Powershell).
Running the command throws back the following error: [image: Error]

For the moment, the registered app has only the following rights in "API permissions":
[image]

Tell, me please, which rights that command demands in order to be successful, as I might need to ask an admin if they require Admin consent?
Or can it be my user's fault that it doesn't have enough rights?

Answer (score 0):

You Need to have Azure AD's [RBAC administrator roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#:%7E:text=Using%20Azure%20Active%20Directory%20%28Azure%20AD%29%2C%20you%20can,passwords%2C%20managing%20user%20licenses%2C%20and%20managing%20domain%20names.) to the user when authenticating with `Connect-AzureAD`,

**For Example :-** *Any of the  Application administrator,Global Administrator, ..etc is required.*

Since, your account doesn't have permission you will return an error message containing "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." Contact your Azure AD admin to grant you the required roles.

Reference [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3072417/authorization-requestdenied-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-op).